# Make attribute have a property set by default

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, properties, default

I use a library that provides an attribute like this:

```
[Attrib] class A { }
```

`Attrib` has an `IsRequired` property that is false by default. I want it to be true by default in my project, but I don't want to add "IsRequired = true" to every usage of the attribute. Is that possible?

I tried subclassing Attrib and marking my classes with the subclass, but that didn't work because the library didn't recognize my subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values must be compile time constants - you have to set `IsRequired = true`.

If `Attrib` allows, you could override this behavior in a subclass and use the subclass.

Don't forget to add the correct namespaces.